# "ERROR: failed to load fw 1", Raspberry Pi 2 B+ LoRa gateway

Tags: raspberry-pi, azure-iot-edge, lorawan

I've been through countless forums discussing the same issue, but with no luck.

I'm trying to setup the WiMOD Lite Gateway (Raspberry Pi 2 B+ and iC880A-SPI) with the [lora_gateway](https://github.com/Lora-net/lora_gateway), but without the [packet_forwarder](https://github.com/Lora-net/packet_forwarder) because I intend to use the [Azure IoT Edge Starterkit](https://github.com/Azure/iotedge-lorawan-starterkit) instead. Before installing that, I want to check the functionality of the lora_gateway, so I'm trying to get the packet logger to work.

When I run the util_pkt_logger, I get the following errors:

```
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: found global configuration file global_conf.json, trying to parse it
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: global_conf.json does contain a JSON object named SX1301_conf, parsing SX1301 parameters
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: lorawan_public 1, clksrc 1
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: radio 0 enabled (type SX1257), center frequency 867500000, RSSI offset -166.000000, tx enabled 0, tx_notch_freq 0
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: radio 1 enabled (type SX1257), center frequency 868500000, RSSI offset -166.000000, tx enabled 0, tx_notch_freq 0
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 0 enabled, radio 1 selected, IF -400000 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 1 enabled, radio 1 selected, IF -200000 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 2 enabled, radio 1 selected, IF 0 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 3 enabled, radio 0 selected, IF -400000 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 4 enabled, radio 0 selected, IF -200000 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 5 enabled, radio 0 selected, IF 0 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 6 enabled, radio 0 selected, IF 200000 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa multi-SF channel 7 enabled, radio 0 selected, IF 400000 Hz, 125 kHz bandwidth, SF 7 to 12
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: LoRa standard channel enabled, radio 1 selected, IF -200000 Hz, 250000 Hz bandwidth, SF 7
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: FSK channel enabled, radio 1 selected, IF 300000 Hz, 125000 Hz bandwidth, 50000 bps datarate
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: global_conf.json does contain a JSON object named gateway_conf, parsing gateway parameters
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: gateway MAC address is configured to AA555A0000000000
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: found local configuration file local_conf.json, trying to parse it
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: local_conf.json does not contain a JSON object named SX1301_conf
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: local_conf.json does contain a JSON object named gateway_conf, parsing gateway parameters
loragw_pkt_logger: INFO: gateway MAC address is configured to AA555A0000000101
ERROR: Failed to load fw 1
ERROR: Version of calibration firmware not expected, actual:0 expected:2
loragw_pkt_logger: ERROR: failed to start the concentrator
```

When I run the util_spi_stress, I get the following:

```
INFO: Starting LoRa concentrator SPI stress-test number 1
Cycle 0 > error during the 1th iteration: write 0x67, read 0x00
Repeat read of target register: 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00
```

Which makes me think that there's something wrong with the configuration of the registers.
I also ran the test_loragw_spi, with this result:

```
Beginning of test for loragw_spi.c
data received (simple read): 7
End of test for loragw_spi.c
```

and the test_loragw_reg, with this result:

```
Beginning of test for loragw_reg.c
Start of register verification
+++MATCH+++ reg number 0 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 1 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 2 read: 103 (67) default: 103 (67)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 3 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 4 read: 53 (35) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 5 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 6 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 7 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 8 read: 8 (8) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 9 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 10 read: 165 (a5) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 11 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 12 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 13 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 14 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 15 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 16 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 17 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 18 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 19 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 20 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 21 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 22 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 23 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 24 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 25 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 26 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 27 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 28 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 29 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 30 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 31 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 32 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 33 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 34 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 35 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 36 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 37 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 38 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 39 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 40 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 41 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 42 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 43 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 44 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 45 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 46 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 47 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 48 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 49 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 50 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 51 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 52 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 53 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 54 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 55 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 56 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 57 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 58 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 59 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 60 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 61 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 62 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 63 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 64 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 65 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 66 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 67 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 68 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 69 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 70 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 71 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 72 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 73 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 74 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 75 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 76 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 77 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 78 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 79 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 80 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 81 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 82 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 83 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 84 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 85 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 86 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 87 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 88 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 89 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 90 read: 7 (7) default: 7 (7)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 91 read: 240 (f0) default: 240 (f0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 92 read: -384 (fffffe80) default: -384 (fffffe80)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 93 read: -128 (ffffff80) default: -128 (ffffff80)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 94 read: 128 (80) default: 128 (80)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 95 read: 384 (180) default: 384 (180)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 96 read: -384 (fffffe80) default: -384 (fffffe80)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 97 read: -128 (ffffff80) default: -128 (ffffff80)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 98 read: 128 (80) default: 128 (80)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 99 read: 384 (180) default: 384 (180)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 100 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 101 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 102 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 103 read: 7 (7) default: 7 (7)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 104 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 105 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 106 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 107 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 108 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 109 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 110 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 111 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 112 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 113 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 114 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 115 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 116 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 117 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 118 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 119 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 120 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 121 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 122 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 123 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 124 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 125 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 126 read: 4 (4) default: 4 (4)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 127 read: 5 (5) default: 5 (5)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 128 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 129 read: 4092 (ffc) default: 4092 (ffc)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 130 read: 7 (7) default: 7 (7)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 131 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 132 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 133 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 134 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 135 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 136 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 137 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 138 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 139 read: 29 (1d) default: 29 (1d)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 140 read: 9 (9) default: 9 (9)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 141 read: 2 (2) default: 2 (2)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 142 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 143 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 144 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 145 read: 2 (2) default: 2 (2)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 146 read: 10 (a) default: 10 (a)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 147 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 148 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 149 read: 8 (8) default: 8 (8)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 150 read: 2 (2) default: 2 (2)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 151 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 152 read: 255 (ff) default: 255 (ff)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 153 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 154 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 155 read: 8 (8) default: 8 (8)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 156 read: 7 (7) default: 7 (7)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 157 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 158 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 159 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 160 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 161 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 162 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 163 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 164 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 165 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 166 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 167 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 168 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 169 read: 32 (20) default: 32 (20)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 170 read: 100 (64) default: 100 (64)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 171 read: 100 (64) default: 100 (64)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 172 read: 7 (7) default: 7 (7)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 173 read: 5 (5) default: 5 (5)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 174 read: 8 (8) default: 8 (8)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 175 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 176 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 177 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 178 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 179 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 180 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 181 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 182 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 183 read: 61447 (f007) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 184 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 185 read: 8 (8) default: 2 (2)
###MISMATCH### reg number 186 read: 6 (6) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 187 read: 31 (1f) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 188 read: -128 (ffffff80) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 189 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 190 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 191 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 192 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 193 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 194 read: 0 (0) default: 5 (5)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 195 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 196 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 197 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 198 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 199 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 200 read: 128 (80) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 201 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 202 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 203 read: 8 (8) default: 2 (2)
###MISMATCH### reg number 204 read: 32799 (801f) default: 10 (a)
###MISMATCH### reg number 205 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 206 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 207 read: 128 (80) default: 10 (a)
###MISMATCH### reg number 208 read: 1 (1) default: 3 (3)
###MISMATCH### reg number 209 read: 0 (0) default: 29 (1d)
###MISMATCH### reg number 210 read: 0 (0) default: 36 (24)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 211 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 212 read: 0 (0) default: 2 (2)
###MISMATCH### reg number 213 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 214 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 215 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 216 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 217 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 218 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 219 read: 0 (0) default: 8 (8)
###MISMATCH### reg number 220 read: 0 (0) default: 3 (3)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 221 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 222 read: 0 (0) default: 7 (7)
###MISMATCH### reg number 223 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 224 read: 0 (0) default: 255 (ff)
###MISMATCH### reg number 225 read: 0 (0) default: 128 (80)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 226 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 227 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 228 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 229 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 230 read: 6 (6) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 231 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 232 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 233 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 234 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 235 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 236 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 237 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 238 read: 1145339392 (44447e00) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 239 read: 68 (44) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 240 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 241 read: 2 (2) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 242 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 243 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 244 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 245 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 246 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 247 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
###MISMATCH### reg number 248 read: 4092 (ffc) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 249 read: 2 (2) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 250 read: 7 (7) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 251 read: 240 (f0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 252 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 253 read: 128 (80) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 254 read: 31 (1f) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 255 read: 128 (80) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 256 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 257 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 258 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 259 read: 0 (0) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 260 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 261 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 262 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 263 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 264 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 265 read: 14 (e) default: 2 (2)
###MISMATCH### reg number 266 read: 1 (1) default: 4 (4)
###MISMATCH### reg number 267 read: 0 (0) default: 2 (2)
###MISMATCH### reg number 268 read: 8 (8) default: 4 (4)
###MISMATCH### reg number 269 read: 31 (1f) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 270 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 272 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 273 read: 128 (80) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 274 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 275 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 276 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 277 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 278 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 279 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 280 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 281 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 282 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 283 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 284 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 285 read: 14 (e) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 286 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 287 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 288 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 289 read: 2113929216 (7e000000) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 290 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 291 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 292 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 293 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 294 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 295 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 296 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 297 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 298 read: 4 (4) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 299 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 300 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 301 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 302 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 303 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 304 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 305 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 306 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 307 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 308 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 309 read: 3 (3) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 310 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 311 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 312 read: 7 (7) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 313 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 314 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 315 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 316 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 317 read: 1 (1) default: 1 (1)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 318 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 319 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 320 read: 2333 (91d) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 321 read: 6 (6) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 322 read: 1 (1) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 323 read: 10 (a) default: 0 (0)
+++MATCH+++ reg number 324 read: 0 (0) default: 0 (0)
###MISMATCH### reg number 325 read: 2 (2) default: 0 (0)
End of register verification
IMPLICIT_PAYLOAD_LENGHT = 0 (should be 197)
FRAME_SYNCH_PEAK2_POS = 2 (should be 11)
PREAMBLE_SYMB1_NB = 10 (should be 49253)
ADJUST_MODEM_START_OFFSET_SF12_RDX4 = 4092 (should be 3173)
IF_FREQ_1 = -128 (should be -1947)
End of test for loragw_reg.c
```

Can you help me figure out what is wrong and how I fix it?

Answer (score 1):

Before using the LoRa concentrator (iC880A-SPI) for any purpose you must reset it through one of the Raspberty PI's GPIO. (You should connect the reset pin of the board to a GPIO port) This is explained in chapter 4.1 of the readme file of the [packet_forwarder](https://github.com/Lora-net/packet_forwarder) app.
Did you reset the concentrator? If not, then that could be the reason of your error message.